# How to block the ability to merge the feature branch into the main branch when a Jenkins pipeline failure?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a branch  "future" , and when the branch does not pass the test, then I need to block the possibility of merging the "feature" branch into the "main" branch. How to do it??

Answer (score 2):

Configure Jenkins to send status checks to Github with the [GitHub Checks plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-checks/).

Then in Github [protect your branch](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches) and disallow merges if any checks have failed. See [Require Status Checks Before Merging](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches#require-status-checks-before-merging).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will definitely try.